# Regular expression error

Tags: regex, find, posix

I have a regular expression that seams to work in Javascript, but doesn't work with the Linux find command. The purpose is to gather a list of files that have been updated in the last 90 days, excluding particular directories (for example, assume I want to include the directory `/data/safe/23/test`, but not `/data/safe/23/skip1`). Here is the regex:

```
^/data/safe/\d{1,4}/(?:(?!skip1|skip2).*)
```

And here is the find command (notice I'm using posix-extended; that may be the problem):

```
find /data/safe -regextype posix-extended -regex '^/data/safe/\d{1,4}/(?:(?!skip1|skip2).*)' -mtime -90
```

And finally this is the error that is generated:

```
find: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that posix-extended does not supports "?:" and "?!".

Anyway, with find, it would be easier to use something like:

```
find /data/safe -regextype posix-extended -regex '^/data/safe/[0-9]{1,4}/.*' ! -regex '^/data/safe/[0-9]{1,4}/(skip1|skip2).*' -mtime -90
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but the command wouldn't execute for some reason (as though it was waiting for further input). So, I removed one of the -regex expressions and now it executes, but doesn't exclude the desired files. find /data/safe -regextype posix-extended ! -regex '^/data/safe/\d{1,4}/(skip1|skip2).*' -mtime -90

Comment: @user1413300 So, actually posix-extended do not supports "\d" as well, need to replace that part with "[0-9]"

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong.  You need to replace the curly brackets with asterisks.  Also you should be piping that whole thing through the tar or touch commands.